# ggplot line legend disappears with alpha < 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

When trying to plot some data in `ggplot2` using `geom_line()`, I noticed that the legend items become empty if I use `alpha` < 1. How can I fix this and why is this happening?

```
# dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:10, 10),
  y = 1:100 + c(runif(50,0,5), runif(50,0,10)),
  grp = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)))

# using alpha on defaul = 1
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, col = grp)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

When I plot the same graph, but with alpha < 1, the lines in the legend completely disappear:

```
# using alpha < 1
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, col = grp)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.9)
```

[image]

(versions: R 4.1.3, ggplot2 3.3.5)

**Edit:** Updating R and restarting RStudio did not help. This also occurs when using R directly without RStudio.

Comment: When I run your code, the lines in the legend do not disappear.

Comment: Yes, this isn't reproducible. Try restarting RStudio and running again, or with a different plotting device like `X11()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. When saving the plots to PDF/PNG the lines do appear in the legend.

Another workaround I found is adding geom_point() so that way at least you have the colors in the legend:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, col = grp)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4, size = 0.1) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4)))
```

Comment: Thank you! For me, the legend is fine as well when exporting, I didn't notice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Legend take the same aes() than plot, you can override this by override.aes.

This should work

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, col = grp)) +
geom_line(alpha = 0.2) + # using alpha = 0.2 to have it more evident
guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

The same can be used for example to change shape or color of legend elements, respect to aes() mapping in plot

Comment: Thanks! This helps me a lot. If I also have transparent points from `geom_point()`, is there a way to only set the alpha of the lines to 1 and keep the transparency of the points?